# Pix2Pix implementation in URP

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, unity-urp

I wanted to implement [this project](https://github.com/keijiro/Pix2Pix) (generating image with deep learning algorithm) in an URP project as a PostProcessing Effect.
I did use ScriptableRenderPass, which sound like the correct way to do it. It work but has lots of issues of lagging. It is completely unplayable, whereas in the Built-in Render pipeline it's running completely normaly.

Here are my script files :

MyBlitRenderPass.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

using Pix2Pix;

class MyBlitRenderPass : ScriptableRenderPass
{
    // used to label this pass in Unity's Frame Debug utility
    string profilerTag;

    string PathToModel;

    Material materialToBlit;
    RenderTargetIdentifier cameraColorTargetIdent;
    RenderTargetHandle tempTexture;

    Dictionary<string, Tensor> _weightTable;
    Generator _generator;

    Shader _shader;

    RenderTexture _sourceRT;
    RenderTexture _resultRT;


    public MyBlitRenderPass(string profilerTag,
      RenderPassEvent renderPassEvent, Material materialToBlit, string PathToModel)
    {
        this.profilerTag = profilerTag;
        this.renderPassEvent = renderPassEvent;
        this.materialToBlit = materialToBlit;
        //this.materialToBlit = materialToBlit;
        this.PathToModel = PathToModel;
    }

    // This isn't part of the ScriptableRenderPass class and is our own addition.
    // For this custom pass we need the camera's color target, so that gets passed in.
    public void Setup(RenderTargetIdentifier cameraColorTargetIdent)
    {



        this.cameraColorTargetIdent = cameraColorTargetIdent;

        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine
            (Application.streamingAssetsPath, PathToModel);


        _weightTable = WeightReader.ReadFromFile(filePath);
        _generator = new Generator(_weightTable);

        _sourceRT = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 0);
        _resultRT = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 0);
        _resultRT.enableRandomWrite = true;

        _sourceRT.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSave;
        _resultRT.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSave;

        _sourceRT.Create();
        _resultRT.Create();
    }

    // called each frame before Execute, use it to set up things the pass will need
    public override void Configure(CommandBuffer cmd, RenderTextureDescriptor cameraTextureDescriptor)
    {
        // create a temporary render texture that matches the camera
        cmd.GetTemporaryRT(tempTexture.id, cameraTextureDescriptor);
    }

    // Execute is called for every eligible camera every frame. It's not called at the moment that
    // rendering is actually taking place, so don't directly execute rendering commands here.
    // Instead use the methods on ScriptableRenderContext to set up instructions.
    // RenderingData provides a bunch of (not very well documented) information about the scene
    // and what's being rendered.
    public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
    {



        // fetch a command buffer to use
        CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get(profilerTag);
        cmd.Clear();


        cmd.Blit(cameraColorTargetIdent, _sourceRT);

        GpuBackend.UseCommandBuffer(cmd);
        _generator.Start(_sourceRT);
        _generator.Step();
        while (_generator.Running) _generator.Step();
        _generator.GetResult(_resultRT);
        GpuBackend.ResetToDefaultCommandBuffer();


        // the actual content of our custom render pass!
        // we apply our material while blitting to a temporary texture
        //cmd.Blit(cameraColorTargetIdent, tempTexture.Identifier(), materialToBlit, 0);
        cmd.Blit(_resultRT, cameraColorTargetIdent);
        // ...then blit it back again 
        //cmd.Blit(tempTexture.Identifier(), cameraColorTargetIdent);

        // don't forget to tell ScriptableRenderContext to actually execute the commands
        context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);

        // tidy up after ourselves
        cmd.Clear();
        CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
    }

    // called after Execute, use it to clean up anything allocated in Configure
    public override void FrameCleanup(CommandBuffer cmd)
    {
        cmd.ReleaseTemporaryRT(tempTexture.id);

        // Release
        if (_generator != null)
        {
            _generator.Dispose();
            _generator = null;
        }


        if (_weightTable != null)
        {
            WeightReader.DisposeTable(_weightTable);
            _weightTable = null;
        }

        RuntimeUtilities.Destroy(_sourceRT);
        RuntimeUtilities.Destroy(_resultRT);

        //base.FrameCleanup();

    }
}
```

MyBlitFeature.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
using System.Collections;


public class MyBlitFeature : ScriptableRendererFeature
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class MyFeatureSettings
    {
        // we're free to put whatever we want here, public fields will be exposed in the inspector
        public bool IsEnabled = true;
        public RenderPassEvent WhenToInsert = RenderPassEvent.AfterRendering;
        public Material MaterialToBlit;
        public string PathToModel;

    }

    // MUST be named "settings" (lowercase) to be shown in the Render Features inspector
    public MyFeatureSettings settings = new MyFeatureSettings();

    RenderTargetHandle renderTextureHandle;
    MyBlitRenderPass myRenderPass;

    public override void Create()
    {
        myRenderPass = new MyBlitRenderPass(
          "My custom pass",
          settings.WhenToInsert,
          settings.MaterialToBlit,
          settings.PathToModel
        );
    }

    // called every frame once per camera
    public override void AddRenderPasses(ScriptableRenderer renderer, ref RenderingData renderingData)
    {
        if (!settings.IsEnabled)
        {
            // we can do nothing this frame if we want
            return;
        }

        // Bout pour gerer la multi-cam VR ?? comment ça marche
        
        ref CameraData cameraData = ref renderingData.cameraData;
        Camera camera = cameraData.camera;
        if (cameraData.isStereoEnabled)
            Debug.Log("Stereo");
            //context.StartMultiEye(camera);
        


        // Gather up and pass any extra information our pass will need.
        // In this case we're getting the camera's color buffer target
        var cameraColorTargetIdent = renderer.cameraColorTarget;
        myRenderPass.Setup(cameraColorTargetIdent);

        // Ask the renderer to add our pass.
        // Could queue up multiple passes and/or pick passes to use
        renderer.EnqueuePass(myRenderPass);
    }
}
```

It follows the logic of the First Pix2Pix [Project implementation](https://github.com/keijiro/Pix2Pix/blob/master/Assets/Pix2Pix/PostProcessing/Pix2PixEffect.cs) :

I know it's very specific, but I really can't figure out where is the issue.

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like that comment is a hint: `It's not called at the moment that rendering is actually taking place, so don't directly execute rendering commands here.` - your code seems to be stalling in the middle of building a command buffer to do a bunch of neural network generation operations, before it finishes what it's doing with the command buffer. You might want to consider moving that interaction with the `Generator` out of this method, and just consume its output after the fact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thought with what method could you run the deep learning interaction ? Does Scriptable render feature has a `render()` method ?

Comment: Have you tried the regular Update loop? Or, if the contents of the Generate method allow, a background thread?

Comment: The function need to have the `ScriptableRenderContext context` as argument